# What magic items can be used to trap/ensnare/capture enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Little bit of background: I'm trying to create a character that's a bounty hunter, and goes around trying to capture wanted outlaws and the occasional monster while keeping them alive. Now, obviously basic things like ropes, chains, manacles, etc are all quite necessary, but I was curious how many magical items there might be that could help me with these endeavors.
If someone could list out some magic items, preferably both attunement and non-attunement items, that would greatly help me out, as I'm not sure what kind of options I might have available to me. Any and all official published material is acceptable (if there's Unearthed Arcana material, I'd like to know that as well if possible).
If it helps, I was planning on making my character a Fighter 6 (Battle Master)/Bard 14 (College of Lore), although that may flex a bit.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for items, or would spells work as well?

Comment: What is your current level? No sense giving you suggestions for things you can't use yet.

Comment: @A.B. Specifically items, although items that give me access to spells are also nice, as there are only so many spells I can get with Magical Secrets.

Comment: @NautArch My DM wants a list of magic stuff we want to aim to obtain throughout our game, so currently level isn't really an issue, but I will be starting at level 5 (probably 2 fighter and 3 bard)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple enough...

*Bead of Force:* Creates a bubble of Force energy. You can roll it around like a hamster ball, and it only lasts for one minute...but anything inside only weighs 1 pound. Bear in mind, it deals some damage when it first goes off...so don't hit fragile targets with it. It is also expended on use.

*Bowl of Commanding Water Elementals:* Bit of an odd choice here, but Water Elementals have a native Grapple ability (Whelm) that they can use to constrain enemies

*Cube of Force (attuned):* Use to create a Cage Match if you get close to an enemy. For one minute, they are trapped within 15 feet of you.

*Dimensional Shackles:* Practically a Must if you intend to capture a spellcaster, as this is the most reliable way to block teleportation long-term.

*Eyes of Charming (attuned):* Charm Person is a great way to get people to willingly come with you.

*Helm of Telepathy (attuned):* Suggestion feature is also great for getting people to surrender and come along.

*Immovable Rod:* Put someone on their stomach, press one of these into the center of their back and push the button. They'll have a devil of a time getting their hands around to de-activate the rod, and they aren't getting up while it is pinning them.

*Iron Bands of Bilarro:* Fling a ball of metal at a target, and it restrains them. DC 20 Str check (once per day) to break free of it.

*Iron Flask:* Only works on creatures from a different plane of existence than the one you are on...but it works *great* for that purpose.

*Mirror of Life Trapping:* Not super portable, it's a 4' tall mirror, but...save or be indefinitely locked inside of one of 12 extradimensional cells. No escape clause except for someone letting you out. Keep this thing's command word a very closely guarded secret so no one can use it against you.

*Rod of Rulership (attuned):* As long as you haven't attacked this person, you can Charm them into thinking you are their leader...and then order them to come with you. It'll wear off in 8 hours, but by then...it'll be too late.

*Rope of Entanglement:* A rope that you can sic on people, and it attempts to tie them up.

*Staff of Charming (Attuned):* Again, magic people into coming along willingly

*Tentacle Rod (Attuned):* Doesn't exactly restrain, but it slows, gives them disadvantage on Dex saves, and seriously interferes with their action economy. They'll have a hard time resisting you in that state.

*Wand of Binding (Attuned):* Lets you cast Hold Person or Hold Monster...paralyzing targets makes them very easy to capture.

*Wand of Paralysis (Attuned):* Basically the same thing as a Wand of Binding

*Wand of Polymorph (Attuned):* Snails are remarkably easy to capture.

*Wand of Web (Attuned):* Fire restraints at your targets

Comment: Thank you very much! There are a lot to choose from, although far too many of them seem to be attunement items unfortunately. Oh well, I'll have to deal with that when  I get to it.